# Remove version from Verdaccio package version history

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, verdaccio

I unpublished the version using `npm unpublish <package-name>@<version-xx>` but i can't find a way to remove the version from verdaccio's (local) ui ?

Any idea ?

Comment: Same problem, I want to remove unpublished package from /verdaccio/storage (I'm using the docker image)

Comment: If you are on linux then check this : https://github.com/verdaccio/verdaccio/issues/365#issuecomment-417906314

Answer (score 5):

```
npm unpublish  --registry http://localhost:4873/ <package-name>@<version-xx> --force
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.