# Remove all packages from locally hosted verdaccio UI

Tags: npm, verdaccio

So, I have `verdaccio` hosted on my local machine. I have a few packages published on it as well with versions. What I want to do is, clear all of these packages with their versions. Like a reset to my `verdaccio`. I can unpublish the packages via `npm unpublish` command, but that would take me time since there are many versions. I am aware a similar question exists here [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65088295/remove-version-from-verdaccio-package-version-history), but it quite doesn't solve my problem.

To summarize, is there any way where I can remove all packages from my local `verdaccio` in one step (or maybe two steps) or any command? Basically a quicker way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a way. Actually this was not what I was looking for, but it solves the problem. So, I can just delete the packages which I do not want from the verdaccio `storage` directory. This directory can be found here:

`C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\verdaccio\storage`

It has sub directories of all the published packages. Just delete the ones which are not needed. I was actually looking for a more `npm` and `verdaccio` command specific way, but this seems to work fine.

Comment: On Mac, the default dir seems to be `~/.local/share/verdaccio/storage`. and I can confirm that deleting this directory will remove all Verdaccio packages